# Match regex that doesn't contain pair of tags

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-validation

I build form to create custom WebForms master pages. I need to validate with regular expression if custom text, that will be placed inside master page, does not contain `<%` and `%>` tags and any text between them. Input can have multiple lines.

Valid input:

```
function() thisCanBeAlsoJavascript() {
    alert("this is safe");
}
```

Invalid input:

```
function() notFunny() {
    alert("I think it's not safe");
    console.log("And this");<% System.Web.HackEverything(); %>

    <%
    Console.WriteLine("This looks dangerous");
    %>
}
Some more text
```

How can I do this? I know I need to use lookarounds to reach the solution. I tried something like this `^(?<!<%)[\s\S]*(?!%>)` for multiline text, but it matches entire invalid text. What should I change?

EDIT:
To make it clear - I use C# DataAnnotations and RegularExpressionAttribute to validate my string. That's why I need regex that not match my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?!.*<%.*%>).*
```

Allow all that does not include `<% ... %>`

if c# == js than you need to replace all `.` with `[\s\S]`. otherwise just add `m` flag for multiline. `m` needed anyway to match `^` to beginning of string.

See https://regex101.com/r/L1Q1lf/1

Comment: I edited my question.
I use C# DataAnnotations and RegularExpressionAttribute to validate my string. This attribute checks if given string is matched to regex, that's why I need something opposite to your answer.

Comment: please use more tags next time. is c# regex the same as JS?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!